# How do I manually update Xcode from 11.2 to 11.2.1?

Tags: xcode, macos, updates

I'm new in the mac world...

11.2.1 ver. is not present in apple store, so i download from apple developer site, now i want update my local versione (11.2).
What steps do I need to follow to update it?

thanks

Comment: Not to sound rude but I found the links to manually download the Xcode.app by Googling `Download xcode manually`. Have you tried that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to update your local installation (nor can you). Both 11.2 and 11.2.1 can run concurrently. So simply drag the Xcode 11.2.1 beta in your Applications folder and start it.
Once this version is available publicly, then you can update your 11.2 through the App Store update process.

Comment: Thanks, is so simply?!? there are really so many differences between windows and mac...

Comment: Yes, in case of Xcode it really is that simple. You can keep Xcode 11.2 for maintaining your released apps and use beta versions to develop feature branches and test your apps for upcmoning iOS / macOS releases.

Comment: I had already tried to unpack the file but I had not copied it to the application folder ... before you answered me, I had already tried, I renamed the xcode folder in xcode11.2, and the folder with the 11.2.1 version I called xcode. then I started the xcode 11.2.1 and everything was ok! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the 11.2.1 file and moved it over to replace the app. The catch is that I am using Visual Studio and Xamarin to build the app. Even though I start XCode on the Mac and see 11.2.1 as the version, it apparently still compiles on my Windows VS system with the 11.2 version. Any ideas?

Comment: it's my own situation, Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin to build the app on Windows PC and one mac in the same LAN. I copy 11.2.1 ver. in Applcation folder and restart Mac and riconnnect VS to Mac. have you tried to publish the app on the store? do you get an error?

Comment: It finally published. What I was apparently missing was an update of Visual Studio on the Mac. After that and a rebuild on Win10, it published with a warning. Thanks for the help.